# Output of exec() in php is empty array

Tags: php

I have the following code to execute `mysqldump` using `exec()`. It was not working and I wanted figure out what output the command line throws. So I printed `$output` and `$worked`. **But all I get is `1` and an empty array**.

Accordong to manual: `If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command.` 
But why is this throwing an empty array? I am including `2>&1` at the end of command as some post suggested, but still not working. I want to know what the terminal is outputting when this command is being executed.

And what does `$worked` outputting `1` mean?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Script:

```
$command='mysqldump --opt -u ' .$db['username'] .' -p' .$db['password'] .' --databases ' .$db['database'] .' > '.$mysqlExportPath .' 2>&1';
$output=array();
exec($command,$output,$worked);

print $worked.'<br>';
print_r($output);
```

Outputs:

```
1
Array ( )
```

Comment: What does it output when run from the command line?

Comment: php does not seem the right tool to do this, you'll probably run into all kinds of permission problems. You should make a simple bash script and have cron run that periodically.

Comment: The 1 it could be the status code of the executed command,

Comment: @Allende: It is and means a warning if `mysqldump` is returning it.

Comment: You should try run it from the command line as @AbraCadaver suggest above

Comment: @AbraCadaver When I run it from the command, it outputs nothing, which means that it is executed without any error. Also the SQL file is generated. However, its not the case when using exec() in php file... (SQL file is not being generated)

Comment: @YunCHan: I bet it is. I bet you are feeding it a relative path and assuming this will work across `exec`. Did you search your hard drive for a similarly-named file in an unexpected place?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know what the terminal is outputting when this command is being executed.

*Nothing*! (And had you simply tried it yourself you'd have seen that immediately). Your command directs the result of `mysqldump` to the file at the path denoted by `$mysqlExportPath`. I don't know why you expect it to go to *stdout* instead.

Perhaps some line breaks would help to make your code a little (no, *substantially*!) more readable:

```
$command
  = 'mysqldump --opt'
  . ' -u ' . $db['username']
  . ' -p' . $db['password']
  . ' --databases ' . $db['database']
  . ' > ' . $mysqlExportPath   // <---- Here you go!
  . ' 2>&1';
```

Remove the redirection, or find the data inside the file `$mysqlExportPath`; your call!

Comment: Even after the execution of that command, the file does not generate in `$mysqlExportPath`. I doubted it is a permission problem, which is why I want to check the error log it might be throwing. Shouldn't that message be in  `$output`?

Comment: @YunCHan: What is `$mysqlExportPath`, exactly? It would be much better if you shrunk your problem example to something short and simple with all the details in it.

Comment: Sorry for insufficient details. `$mysqlExportPath .= "/backup_$date.sql";`. The thing is this script works fine in my local server.

Comment: @Yun: Try it with `shell_exec` instead of `exec`; perhaps your default execution environment is not a shell and thus the redirection fails

Comment: Manual about shell_exec says, `This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required. `

Comment: Will there be an error log being generated when exec fails??